# Regex that matches not when string is duplicated

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression, that matches
`foo`
but not
`foofoo`

I tried to go with `foo(?!foo)` but this matches the the second foo in `foofoo`.
How can i modify this regex go only match `foo` but not `foofoo`.

Comment: May be word boundaries: `\bfoo\b`? what is your regex platform?

Comment: If it is in the middle of a word then use `(?<!foo)foo(?!foo)`

Comment: @anubhava This is it. I didn't know about negative look-behind yet. If you post this as answer I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `foo` is a complete word then use word boundaries:

```
\bfoo\b
```

If it is in the middle of a word then use a negative lookahead and lookbehind;

```
(?<!foo)foo(?!foo)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0uyJIu/1)

Here:

- `(?<!foo)`: Assert that we don't have `foo` at previous position
- `foo`: Match text `foo`
- `(?!foo)`: Assert that we don't have `foo` ahead